# How to use a custom express-validator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I'm developing a register form and I'm using `express-validator` to validate fields but I'm having troubles in validate if email already exists.

I did a select to check if the inserted email already exists but it returns me always that email exists.

I tried other ways but didn't work.

This is my `post request`:

```
routes.post('/register', function(req,res)
{
    var email = req.body.email;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;

    // Validation
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email already exists').custom(value => {
    return User.findUserByEmail(value).then(function(user) {
      throw new Error('this email is already in use');
    })
  });

    req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
    console.log(errors);
        res.render('register',{
            errors:errors
        });
    } else {
    console.log("passed");

        var newUser = {
            email:email,
            username: username,
            password: password
        };


        User.createUser(newUser, function(err, User){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(User);
        });

        req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now login');

        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

And my function `findUserByEmail`:

```
module.exports.findUserByEmail = function(email, callback){
  var connection = db.setDB('DB1');
  connection.then(result => {
    var request = new mssql.Request(conn);
    console.log("SELECT * FROM u_users WHERE email = '"+email+"'");
    var exists = request.query("SELECT * FROM u_users WHERE email = '"+email+"'");

    Promise.all([exists]).then(function(results)
    {

      console.log(results);
      if(results[0].length == 0)
      {
        console.log("1");
        return false;
      }
      console.log("2");
      return true;
    }).catch(function(err)
    {
      console.log("Error verifying email...");
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
}
```

If I do this way it returns me an error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.`, this happens because you're not returning the promise from your `findUserByEmail` function.

In addition to this, your custom validator will *always* fail if you keep it as is.

Your `findUserByEmail` is only returning `true`/`false`, what means "resolve this promise with this value".
You might want to change it to return the found user (and also make its name suggest what it really does!):

```
module.exports.findUserByEmail = function(email, callback){

    var request = new mssql.Request(conn);
    console.log("SELECT * FROM u_users WHERE email = '"+email+"'");
    var query = request.query("SELECT * FROM u_users WHERE email = '"+email+"'");

    return query.then(function(results) {
      return results[0];
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Error verifying email...");
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    });
}
```

Now you need to make your custom validator check if any user was returned from that function:

```
req.checkBody('email', 'Email already exists').custom(value => {
    return User.findUserByEmail(value).then(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            throw new Error('this email is already in use');
        }
    })
});
```

And you're done!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already have the error and I think it's because I try to make a connection with then. I don't put this part of code because I thought that it's not the problem because I do this in other places in project and works fine. But I update the question with connection then. I appreciate if you can help me again. @gustavohenke

Comment: You still need to return.